# Is it possible to find angles and length of woods?

Tags: calculus, geometry, trigonometry, soft-question, applications

With respect to the picture below, is it possible to find the angles and the length of the wooden bars, if we have no further information? Any hint or clue would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Are those angles given? Those you pointed on

Comment: One needs some additional info.

Comment: @DjuraMarinkov:No,I want to find them

Comment: [+1] Interesting question.

Comment: A trapezoid is not fixed by its height and the lengths of its bases.

Comment: **Assuming** (reasonably?) that the $25$cm top bar is centered over the parallel $40$cm bottom bar, the wooden bar marked $L$ is the hypotenuse of a right triangle with legs $119.5$cm and $\frac12(40 + 25 )$cm. Pythagoras and an arctangent will provide the length and the angle measure you seek. (The perpendicular $40$cm bar is irrelevant.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment: **Assuming** that the $25$cm top bar is centered over the parallel $40$cm bottom bar, ...

[image]

$$\tan\theta = \frac{239/2}{(40+25)/2} = \frac{239}{65} \quad\to\quad \theta = \operatorname{atan}\frac{239}{65} = 74.785\ldots^\circ$$

$$L = \sqrt{\left(\frac{239}{2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{40+25}{2}\right)^2} = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{239^2+65^2} = 123.841\ldots$$

Comment: your answer is very simple and effective. Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

If the lamp is exactly right above the midpoint of the base, then the angle is about $74.785°$ and the longer and shorter pieces are $76.21$ and $47.63$ respectively.
[image]